# Include an HTML file in a ion-view

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have already an exsisting html file which use another librairies and stuff, I want to use in my new ionic application.

So I would like to use it as an ion-view. so I would like to know if it would be possible to include an html file in the ion-view ? which look like :

```
<ion-view>
<io-content>

</ion-view>
</ion-content>
```

this is the existing HMTL file where I use different libraries and css file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="./assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./assets/css/ofc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="./assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pouchdb-3.4.0.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="blob-util.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"> </script>
<script src="properties.js"> </script>


</head> 
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="p1">



</div>




<script src="core.js"></script>


</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do this? I believe this question comes from a problem you haven't described yet.

Normally all libraries used in an Ionic app are included in the index.html and not within each `<ion-view>` or `<ion-content>`. In these Ionic directives you only load the HTML needed for that view.

I suggest you start reading from the beginning:

- [Getting Started with Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)
- [Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/)
- [CodePen examples Ionic](http://codepen.io/ionic/public-list/)